# What product is AWS Elastic Laod Balancer behind the scenes

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing

Does someone know what kind of product is working behind the scenes as `AWS Elastic Loadbalancer`?

Could likely be something as haproxy, nginx, etc. Does someone know more respectively has any proof for something?

Ideally I would like to use the underlying product directly. Therefore I would like to understand if/what they use and ideally understand what the characteristics of this setup are so that I can apply it to my own.

Comment: Questions like "What's the secret sauce behind vendor X's product Y?" are not good questions here, unless you can explain how the answer will relate to a professional sysadmin problem that you're trying to solve.

Comment: Ideally would like to use the underlying product directly. Therefore I would like to understand if/what they use and ideally understand what the characteristics of this setup are so that I can apply it to my own.

Answer (score 3):

I doubt you'll get a positive answer. They may well use something like HAProxy, but the nature of the abstraction provided by ELB means they could probably swap that out for something else at any time. Also they probably have their own modifications to whatever they're using.

However, if you're interested in the design of Load-Balancing-as-a-Service in general then you may like to take a look at OpenStack Neutron LBaaS. You can [browse the source here](https://github.com/openstack/neutron-lbaas), and there's an [architecture diagram here](https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Neutron_LBaaS_Arch). I think HAProxy is the most common underlying LB software, but it also supports [other products](https://github.com/openstack/neutron-lbaas/tree/master/neutron_lbaas/services/loadbalancer/drivers) too.

Comment: Thanks for your information. Helpful but not the answer I'm looking for ;)